# getPerspectiveTransform Assertion error openCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm creating a script with opencv for detect game cards. As input image i give this one [image]

And i've wrote this for detect the cards contours

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

im = cv2.imread('/home/pero/PycharmProjects/image-recognition/python/cards.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (1, 1), 1000)
flag, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)


contourns_to_draw = []

# filter the cards contour
for i in range(len(contours)):
    card = contours[i]
    peri = cv2.arcLength(card, True)
    if peri > 800:
        contourns_to_draw.append(card)

img = cv2.drawContours(im, contourns_to_draw, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.imshow("Show Boxes", img)
key = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF

# Should create a new image by the given card contour ( NOT WORK )
for i, contour in enumerate(contourns_to_draw):

    peri = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.02 * peri, True)
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contour)
    r = cv2.boxPoints(rect)

    h = np.array([[0, 0], [449, 0], [449, 449], [0, 449]], np.float32)
    transform = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(approx, h)
    warp = cv2.warpPerspective(im, transform, (450, 450))


    # cv2.imshow("Show Boxes", cropped)
    # key = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
    # if key == 27:
    #     break
    # cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    break
```

The cards contours are detected but when i try to get the single card image, for understand what card is, it gives me an error. The error is raise when i call the method `transform = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(approx, h)`  and the error is this one

**ERROR**

```
transform = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(approx, h)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:3157:
error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 4 && dst.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 4 in function 'getPerspectiveTransform'
```

I'm following  [this guide](https://arnab.org/blog/so-i-suck-24-automating-card-games-using-opencv-and-python) and trying to understand whet he does step by step but i got stuck with that line.

I want only to copy the area inside the card contour ,save it as another image and after campare that image with other images for detect what card is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `approx` is `np.int32`. So you want to do:

```
transform = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(approx.astype(np.float32), h)
```

Comment: There are other ways that can accomplish the task to copy the contourned area?

Comment: Are you asking for `minAeraRect`?

Comment: I saw that method but it's better the one that i was using. My problem is that when i try to use that code the wrap image that should bet the copy of the inner area of the contour (depending on the image that i use) is rotate or flipped or both and i don't understand why

Comment: Because the contour is in random rotation (clockwise or counter-clockwise). You could reorder the contours, e.g. starting at the bottom-left and go counter-clockwise and arrange the target corners accordingly.

Comment: ok thanks, i'm gonna search for it, do you have some usfull links?